# Can't find Code first from database when creating Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework

When I'm trying to create an Entity data model i dont get the option "Code first from database". i only got "Generate from Database" and "Empty model"

Im using this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/data/jj200620.aspx

Cant find any solution for this.

Comment: Do you have the same Visual Studio version & edition?

Comment: VS13 Pro and EF 6.1. very strange.. :/

Answer (score 4):

The new Entity Framework tooling is in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 CTP 2...
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42023

You can also reverse engineer Code First models from an existing database using a Visual Studio addin such as Entity Framework Power Tools (some of them became the new tooling added to Update 2)...
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Comment: I installed VS2013 Update 2 supposedly successfully, and now the ADO.NET Entity template is completely missing. Package Manger says EF 6.1.0 is part of my solution and the references are there, but I cannot run the ADO.NET Entity Data Model wizard since not there.

Comment: I think my problem was related to having first installed just EF 6.1.0 Tools by themselves, then uninstalling them and installing Update2. A total uninstall and reinstall of VS2013 w/ Update 2 integrated fixed the problem. Sure takes a long time to do that though.

Comment: MSFT really needs to speedup uninstall and install. The reverse engineering worked well though. I'm finally giving up on Model First as clearly MSFT is putting their efforts into Code First, which I find tedious and error prone for navigation as compared to using the designer. Sure would be nice if CF, MF and DF were completely interchangeable in the design process where you could take advantages of each approach as desired. I would like to see a diagram of Code First classes, be able to import database changes, and export class changes to the database and use the designer for associations.

Answer (score 1):

Update the visual studio to the last version (update 4).

Tools - > extensions and update